# How to play an mp3 with Apache Royale

Tags: mp3, media-player, apache-royale

All is in title.

Is there an easy way to play an mp3 and/or show a basic mp3 player (track / play /pause) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution : wrapping a javascript player like https://github.com/kodedninja/microne